# 3 cascading dropdown for country, state and city in angular4

Tags: angular

I want to show 3 cascade dropdown for country ,state and city. 
i got state for country id, but for city i am not getting.
here is my html code

```
<div>
        <label>State:</label>
        <select class="full-width">
          <option *ngIf='selectedCountry.id == 0' value="0">--Select--
</option>
          <option *ngFor="let state of states " value= {{state.id}}>
 {{state.name}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>City:</label>
        <select class="full-width">
          <option *ngIf='selectedCountry.id == 0' value="0">--Select--</option>
          <option *ngFor="let citi of cities " value= {{citi.id}}>{{citi.name}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
```

here is the code for getting country and state:

```
onSelect(countryid) {
this.states = this.dataServie.getStates().filter((item)=> 
item.countryid == countryid);
//this.states = this._dataService.getStates().filter((item)=> 
item.countryid == countryid);
}
```

here is country.ts code :

```
export class Country {
constructor(public id: number, public name: string) { }
}

export class State {
constructor(public id: number, public countryid: number, public name: 
 string) { }
}
```

here is the code for city.ts :

```
export class City {
constructor( public stateid: number, public name: string) { }
}
```

i am not getting how i call city of perticular state id
Could any one help me out.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a function that retrieves the cities and saves it in your controller. Similar to onSelect(countryid) you need to make a selectState(stateid) function that retrieves and assigns cities to this.cities.

Also city is not spelled citi.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to the **Template**

```
<label>State:</label>
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedState.id" (change)="select($event.target.value)">
  <option *ngFor="#state of states " value= {{state.id}}>{{state.name}}</option>
</select>

<label>city </label> 
<select>
  <option *ngFor="#city of cities " value= {{city.id}}>{{city.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Add this to **component**

```
  select(stateid){
    this.cities = this._dataService.getCities().filter((item)=> item.stateid == stateid);

  }
```

Working Plunker for the same [LINK](https://plnkr.co/edit/ywkAlWM4NimtNvhqx917?p=preview)

Comment: @rahul-sigh nice it works but there is an error when you select a country , state and city and you change the country dropdown  , the state dropdown get empty but the city dropdown stays with the same value .